# Qt - Create a time-based UUID

Tags: c++, qt, uuid

I want to create v1 UUID (time-based) in Qt

I tried using [cppuuid](https://github.com/sean-/ossp-uuid) but couldn't get correct uuid
I also tried [ossp uuid](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/) but got error while building, and I prefer to avoid using it anyway

***I need the most simple and short way to generate such uuid in Qt (I prefer a Qt class, if any)***

I want v1 uuid's to use it as a primary key in my database

see [//https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/](http:////https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/)

**I tried cppuuid as follows**

```
    qulonglong v1 = 0x19432987;
    qulonglong v2= 0x33;

    uuid::Uuid u = uuid::uuid1( v1,v2 );

    QByteArray uuid = QByteArray().append( QString::fromStdString( u.hex()));

    qDebug() << "uuid size" << uuid.size(); // 25
    qDebug() << "uuid" << uuid;
    qDebug() << "uuid hex" << uuid.toHex();
    qDebug() << "uuid hex size" << uuid.toHex().size(); //50
```

**Edit**: I have found why cppuuid was giving wrong results, details are in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a logic error in cppuuid which caused strange results.

The gettime function in cppuuid is as follows:

```
static uint64_t gettime()
{
    static uint64_t last_uuid_time = 0; // On the heap!
    int rc = 0;
    struct timespec tp;
    uint64_t uuid_time = 0;

    rc = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);

    // Convert to 100-nanosecond intervals
    uuid_time = tp.tv_sec * 10000000;
    uuid_time = uuid_time + (tp.tv_nsec / 100);
    uuid_time = uuid_time + kNum_100nsec_1582_1970;

    // If the clock looks like it went backwards, or is the same, increment it.
    if (last_uuid_time <= uuid_time) {
    uuid_time = last_uuid_time + 1;
    }
    last_uuid_time = uuid_time;

    return uuid_time;
}
```

The login error is in this *if condition*

```
    // If the clock looks like it went backwards, or is the same, increment it.
if (last_uuid_time <= uuid_time) {
    uuid_time = last_uuid_time + 1;
}
```

the

> <=

should be

> >=

now cppuuid is giving correct results. Hope this helps

```
uuid::Uuid u = uuid::uuid1(0x19432987, 0x33);

QByteArray uuid = QByteArray().append( QString::fromStdString( u.hex()));

qDebug() << "uuid size" << uuid.size(); // 32
qDebug() << "uuid" << uuid;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `QUuid::createUuid` which is seeded by the local random number generator. You can seed with `qsrand(time())` or something similar.